# Why can't I set a JavaScript prototype inside a function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why can't I set the prototype inside of a function?
For example why does this not work?

```
var Bar = function(){
   this.name='Bar'
}

var barProto = new Bar()  

var Foo = function(){
    this.prototype= barProto
}

var foo = new Foo()
console.log(foo.name) // undefined
```

But this does work:

```
var Bar = function(){
   this.name='Bar'
}

var barProto = new Bar()  

var Foo = function(){

}

Foo.prototype= barProto

var foo = new Foo()

console.log(foo.name) // Bar
```

I don't like the syntax of assigning the prototype after I have created the function.

Answer (score 5):

```
this.prototype= barProto
```

is not equivalent to

```
Foo.prototype= barProto
```

`this` refers to a specific object which will be created by new Foo()

Foo is the constructor function.  You set the prototype on the constructor, not on a specific instance.

More info on prototypical inheritance here: [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 2):

Because `this.prototype` is not the same as `Foo.prototype`. When `Foo` is called with `new`, any reference to `this` inside it will refer to the instance being created.

Comment: I sorta get what you are saying. But don't I want the new object that is created to have the prototype barProto, right? Does the prototype only get set when "new" is used? Why can't I set the prototype property of any object at any time?

Comment: What I'm saying is exactly the same as ben336. "Why can't I set the prototype property of any object at any time?" - that's how the language works... Maybe you prefer `var foo = Object.create(barProto)`? That works too, and doesn't require the `Foo` constructor or the `new` keyword.